# Snapshot max depth doesn’t work after upgrading to react native 0.6.3

Tags: appium, appium-ios

Snapshot max depth doesn’t work after upgrading to react native 5. Using latest react native libraries (Before react native 5), was possible for us to locate elements using snapshotMax depth as capability.

Can you please help me to solve this issue?
Thanks,

Comment: Hi Jose
Did u find any solution.